# AD User created by application isn't properly resolving to a upn suffix

Tags: c#, active-directory, dynamics-crm-2013

I am working on some code that creates an AD user programmatically (to be pulled into a MS DYnamics CRM 2013 environment), and the code works with one weird quirk. I have a list of UPN's created on our AD structure, but for some reason my AD users aren't resolving to them.

So, I have a list of UPN suffix's that include example.com. I set the username to be first.last@example.com, and it's not letting me use this to sign in to CRM. When I check the AD entry, I can see that it kind of correctly assigned the logon name to first.last@example.com, but @example.com appears in the list twice, the entry that was actually created and this new one. So it's not recognizing that @example.com is a pre-existing UPN suffix, and I can't use the first.last@example.com to sign in to CRM with, I have to use the example.local\first.last. I hope this made sense. Thank you very much.

So how do I tell then AD record when it signs in to use the pre-existing UPN and not... do whatever it's doing? Here's my code:

```
try
        {
            string connectionPrefix = "LDAP://" + ldapPath;// ldapPart;// ldapPath
            var adminUsername = ConfigurationHelper.GetConfigSettingByName(orgservice,
                            "ADPasswordReset.AdminUsername", unsecureConfig, secureConfig);
            var adminPassword = ConfigurationHelper.GetConfigSettingByName(orgservice,
                            "ADPasswordReset.AdminPassword", unsecureConfig, secureConfig);

            if (CheckIfUserExists(getSAMNameFromUserName(userName), trace) == true)
            {
                throw new Exception("A User with that name already exists.");
            }

            DirectoryEntry dirEntry = new DirectoryEntry(connectionPrefix, adminUsername, adminPassword, AuthenticationTypes.Secure);
            DirectoryEntry newUser;
            string cn = firstName + " " + lastName;
            newUser = dirEntry.Children.Add("CN=" + cn, "user"); //display name - This is the "Display" name that shows up on the AD list. 
            newUser.Properties["displayName"].Value = cn;
            newUser.Properties["samAccountName"].Value = getSAMNameFromUserName(userName);//userName; 
            newUser.Properties["userPrincipalName"].Value = checkUserName(userName);
            newUser.Properties["givenName"].Value = firstName; //Firstname
            newUser.Properties["sn"].Value = lastName; //Lastname? -Surname
            newUser.Properties["LockOutTime"].Value = 0; //unlock account. Set this to 0 to unlock the account.
            newUser.CommitChanges();
            oGUID = newUser.Guid.ToString();

            //Must be handled after the previous stuff. Unsure why.
            newUser.Invoke("SetPassword", new object[] { userPassword });
            newUser.CommitChanges();

            //For some reason, can't be handled before the password is set?
            newUser.Properties["userAccountControl"].Value = 0x0200; //0x0200
            newUser.CommitChanges();
            dirEntry.Close();
            newUser.Close();
        }

    public static string checkUserName(string userName)
    {
        if (!userName.Contains("@"))
        {
            return userName + "@example.local";
        }

        return userName;
    }

    public static string getSAMNameFromUserName(string domainUserName)
    {
        int stop;
        string s = domainUserName;

        if (s.Contains("@"))
        {
            stop = s.IndexOf("@");
            return (stop > -1) ? s.Substring(0, stop) : string.Empty;
        }
        return domainUserName;// string.Empty;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all who took the time to help.

Whitespace. Grrr, whitespace.

For anybody who comes across this thread in the future, the problem was that something during the AD creation was appending whitespace to my username and domain. So instead of "example.com" it was saving the domain as "example.com " (notice the whitespace at the end?). I .Trim()'d everything and it appears to be working just fine. :)

My new code becomes:

```
    public static string checkUserName(string userName)
    {
        if (!userName.Contains("@"))
        {
            return userName.Trim() + "@domain.local".Trim();
        }

        return userName.Trim();
    }


try
        {
            string connectionPrefix = "LDAP://" + ldapPath;// ldapPart;// ldapPath
            var adminUserName = GetAdminUserName(orgservice, unsecureConfig, secureConfig);
            var adminPassword = GetAdminPassword(orgservice, unsecureConfig, secureConfig);

            if (CheckIfUserExists(getSAMNameFromUserName(userName), trace) == true)
            {
                trace.Trace("About to handle success. A User already exists: " + getSAMNameFromUserName(userName));
                trace.HandleSuccess();
                throw new Exception("User " + getSAMNameFromUserName(userName) + " already exists.");
            }

            DirectoryEntry dirEntry = new DirectoryEntry(connectionPrefix, adminUserName, adminPassword, AuthenticationTypes.Secure);
            DirectoryEntry newUser;
            string cn = firstName.Trim() + " " + lastName.Trim();
            newUser = dirEntry.Children.Add("CN=" + cn, "user"); //display name - This is the "Display" name that shows up on the AD list. 
            newUser.Properties["displayName"].Value = cn;
            newUser.Properties["samAccountName"].Value = getSAMNameFromUserName(userName).Trim();
            newUser.Properties["userPrincipalName"].Value = checkUserName(userName).Trim();
            newUser.Properties["givenName"].Value = firstName.Trim(); //Firstname
            newUser.Properties["sn"].Value = lastName.Trim(); //Lastname? -Surname
            //newUser.Properties["LockOutTime"].Value = 0; //unlock account. Set this to 0 to unlock the account.
            newUser.CommitChanges();
            oGUID = newUser.Guid.ToString();

            //Must be handled after the previous stuff. Unsure why.
            newUser.Invoke("SetPassword", new object[] { userPassword });
            newUser.CommitChanges();

            //For some reason, can't be handled before the password is set?
            newUser.Properties["userAccountControl"].Value = 0x10200; //0x0200
            newUser.CommitChanges();

            //http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20710535/is-there-a-way-to-set-a-new-users-domain-suffix-through-the-userprincipal-class
            newUser.Close();
            dirEntry.Close();
            //newUser.Close(); //Close user first, then dirEntry because of the heirarchy call?
        }
        catch (System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryServicesCOMException E)
        {
            System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryServicesCOMException newE = new System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryServicesCOMException(E.Message);
            //DoSomethingwith --> E.Message.ToString();
            throw newE;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code you set the UPN to `example.local` not `example.com`:

```
public static string checkUserName(string userName)
{
    if (!userName.Contains("@"))
    {
        return userName + "@example.local";
    }

    return userName;
}
```

A user can only have one UPN even if the domain has multiple possible suffixes configured. If you want `username@example.com` to resolve, the user must have `example.com` set as it's suffix.

Comment: Thank you for replying, Ashigore. me@example.com could be what's being passed in as userName though. If the user chooses first.last instead of an email address then it appends example.local. Otherwise, it simply returns the email address because we presume we have the domain set up in AD already. The problem is that isn't recognizing that the domain is registered, and so it creates it twice.

Comment: @JoshAlcorn You can't use a user's email address as a username though, unless it's configured as their UPN.

Comment: Hello Ashigore. The users in question will be using their email address as their upn. The domain for these email address is registered in my active directory. Creating an AD account by email puts the domain on my list twice, and doesn't allow them to physically sign in using their email address. I hope this makes sense. All of our AD users to this point were created by hand, and I used an email address to register them. I'm ONLY having an issue doing it programatically. Hopefully this image elaborates better then I can. http://i.imgur.com/Cif5aed.png

Comment: @JoshAlcorn OK I think I understand now. I suggest trying to creating the user without specifying a UPN (ie it is created with the default one), and then change it afterwards. See if that makes a difference.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. It fixed the dual UPN entry problem but I'm still unable to use the email addresses to sign into our CRM for some reason. WHen I create AD users by hand, the email signin works as expected however. I'm investigating it now but if you have any suggestions I'd be happy to hear them. Thank you tremendously for your help.

Comment: As an aside, I just migrated the sandbox crm I've been using to test these programatically created AD users from 2013 to 2015, and during the migration it gave me errors mapping the test users I've been creating, but all users created by hand worked as intended. So infuriating......

Comment: I stand corrected. It did NOT fix my problem, the upn is still appearing on the list twice. Still pretty infuriating.

Comment: @JoshAlcorn Did you try setting the UPN after creating the user?

Comment: I did. I've even tried switching the order samaccountname and upn are set, etc. Nothing seems to be helping.

Comment: See my answer below. @Ashigore, thank you tremendously for your help. I don't know that I would have solved this on my own.